# VPN (Windows 7) & local (physical) network access

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

I've set up a VPN (on a synology server) located at my home, to which I connect using the windows 7 VPN (PPTP connection).

When I connect to the VPN while at work, I can see my external IP address changing (for my home IP), and I can access my home LAN ressources (my router for instance). However, I can still access the "network shares" of my work (which is normally impossible from my home LAN. To access these shares from an external network, I need to use my work VPN).

My home LAN is configured on the  192.168.1.x network, the VPN is configured with the 10.0.0.x network, and my work network is configured on the 192.168.17.x range.

Is is because the work network is configured through a Windows Domain? I tried disabling the wifi connection (but I don't think it has anything to do with it).

I would like to make sure that when connected to this VPN, I am completely "outside" of the work network, and being able to access my work shares indicates that it's not fully the case.

Comment: As you describe the configuration.  You are not disconnecting from your work network when you connected to your private vpn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VPN client is implementing a feature known as [Split Tunneling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling). This allows the VPN to route traffic destined for the remote network put the VPN miniport virtual network adapter and into the VPN tunnel, but to send traffic for all other locations out the physical NIC to the physical LAN. If you disable split tunneling, all traffic from your machine will cross the VPN link to the remote network.

On windows they don't make it easy to disable split tunneling, because its handled by the order in which network interfaces are bound. The Cisco VPN client makes it much easier (just a checkbox), but for windows, it involves a registery hack. see more here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/19d54ebd-a7f8-4ded-8204-7ba35034fc90/vpn-doesnt-respect-advanced-network-setting?forum=w7itpronetworking

Personally, I'd recommend using the Cisco or other VPN client.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Makes sense now.

Regarding the "anonymity" of this setup, would someone connected on my local network be able to "sniff" packets (or a transparent proxy) from the internet connection? Or is it "concealed" by the VPN connection?

Comment: traffic being routed into the VPN tunnel should be indecipherable to outside observers. You should be safe from proxies as well, as the VPN's key interchange should detect interception enroute. That said though, PPTP has a history of flaws that may or may not comprimise those protections. I suppose to know for sure, we'd have to know what proxy (ie websense?) your adversary is implementing.